# Creating a new data frame column that sums multiple correct answers

Tags: r, testing, count, sum, points

My dataframe contains the responses my students provided in an online exam/ test and I'm after some help in analyzing one of the questions.
It's a little tricky to explain how the question was structured but I'll do my best.
Each participant was put in two weather scenarios (which were chosen randomly between 5 possible scenarios: Storm, Wind, Persistent, Wet & Ldry)

They were then asked to state whether 6 different travel techniques were applicable in their two scenarios. For simplification purposes, the travel techniques were (Chute, Lee, Early, Wait48, Solar & Conn).

All students were asked had to state how applicable each travel technique would be in each weather scenario and the options they had to choose between were: NA) don't know 0) not applicable 1) somewhat applicable 2) highly applicable.

For each of the 5 weather scenarios, there is 1 travel technique that is highly applicable, apart from for wet, which has 2 techniques that are highly applicable.

Correct highly applicable answers are follows:
Storm: Wait48, Wind: Lee, Persistent: Conn, Wet: Early & Solar, Ldry: Chute

What I'm interested in asking here, is how can I create a new column in my DF, that tallies up whether each student (each row) got none of the 'highly applicables' correct, got 1 correct, or got 2?

```
# Example results table
# Note the numbers relate to the student's responses as follows:
# 0= Not applicable, 1= Somewhat Applicable, 2= Highly applicable, NA = 
  Don't know
WeatherScen1 <- c('storm', 'persistent', 'wet', 'wet', 'storm', 'wind', 
'Ldry')
Solar1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 0, 0, NA, 2)
Conn1 <- c(1, 2, 0, 2, 0, NA, 1)
Chute1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, NA, 1)
Early1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 1, 1, NA, 2)
Wait481 <- c(2, 0, 0, 2, 1, NA, 2)
Lee1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1)
WeatherScen2 <- c('wet', 'wet', 'wind', 'storm', 'Ldry', 'storm', 
'persistent')
Solar2 <- c(2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Conn2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2)
Chute2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Early2 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
Wait482 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0)
Lee2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0)

WeatherScenResp <- data.frame(WeatherScen1, Solar1, Conn1, Chute1, Early1, 
Wait481, Lee1, WeatherScen2, Solar2, Conn2, Chute2, Early2, Wait482, Lee2)
View(WeatherScenResp)

Id WeatherScen1 Solar1 Conn1 Chute1 Early1 Wait481 Lee1... 
1  Storm        0      1     1      0      2       1   ... 
2  Persistent   1      2     1      1      0       1   ... 
3  Wet          2      0     1      2      0       1   ...
4  Wet          0      2     2      1      2       0   ... 
5  Storm        0      0     2      1      1       1   ... 
6  Wind         NA     NA    NA     NA     NA      NA  ... 
7  Ldry         2      1     1      2      2       1   ... 


...WeatherScen2 Solar2 Conn2 Chute2 Early2 Wait482 Lee2
...Wet          2      0     1      2      0       1
...Wet          2      0     1      2      0       1
...Wind         0      1     1      1      1       2
...Storm        0      1     1      1      1       1
...Ldry         0      0     1      1      1       1
...Storm        1      1     1      1      2       1
...Persistent   0      2     1      0      0       0
```

If we just focus on whether students were able to correctly identify the travel techniques that are highly applicable (2s), then rows/ students 1, 2 & 3 got both their weather scenarios correct, students/rows 4 & 5 got both weather scenarios wrong and students/rows 6 & 7 got their first scenario wrong but their second right.

How can I create an additional column called something like 'no of highly applicables correct' that would display 2 points for students 1 2 & 3, 0 points for students 4 & 5 and 1 point for students 6 & 7?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: $interestedfinnfisher, what does your DF look like? You've only given us vectors so far. Are all these columns?

Comment: Is `Loose` the same as `Ldry`?

Comment: Hi Sven and AntoniosK, I have added in a data frame above and I have edited the text, indeed Ldry and Loose were the same, they now all say Ldry